# Remove from either one character in Oracle query

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

```
Sample Mail ID: maniyuva21_etc@xyz.com
```

Here I should remove chars from `_etc`. But in same way if `_etc` is not available in some mail ID then should remove from `@`.

So my result will be `maniyuva21`

I need this to be done in Oracle query

Comment: Add some more rows of sample data, and its expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [**`REGEX_REPLACE`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm).

**Example** from *SQLPLUS*:

```
SQL> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('maniyuva21_etc@xyz.com', '(_etc)?@.*$', '') FROM dual;

REGEXP_REP
----------
maniyuva21

SQL> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('maniyuva21@xyz.com', '(_etc)?@.*$', '') FROM dual;

REGEXP_REP
----------
maniyuva21
```

**NOTE**: Oracle engine must be >= 10g

Comment: Thanks. Now I have another one small change when I am doing my testing (Sorry for this). Some are with '_etc' and some are with only '_et'. How to handle this?

Comment: Use `'(_etc|_et)?@.*$'` or `'(_et[c]?)?@.*$'` in the regex

Comment: Really Thanks. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **`CASE`** expression to check whether the email string contains `_etc` or not. Then use a combination of **[`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)** and **[`INSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm)** to extract the required part.

**Query**

```
select email_column,
case when email_column like '%_etc@%'
then substr(email_column, 1, instr(email_column, '_etc@', 1) - 1)
else substr(email_column, 1, instr(email_column, '@', 1) - 1) end as new_email_column
from your_emails_table;
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I have another one small change when I am doing my testing (Sorry for this).  Some are with '_etc' and some are with only '_et'. How to handle this?